# My for loop is breaking my code

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Here's the for loop in question:

```
console.log(sender1[0]); // returns user object
console.log(sender1.length); // returns 1
for (var i = 0; i < sender1.length; i = i + 1) {
    console.log(sender1[i].phone); // returns can't read phone property of undefined
}
```

Here's where I'm getting sender 1

```
User.find().where({
    code: req.body.Body.toUpperCase()
}).exec(function (err, sender1) {
```

This is using mongoose, so sender1 is already an array. I tried using .toArray and it said find has no method "toArray".

If I replace all the sender[i] with sender[0], everything works fine.
But it's saying sender[i].somename is undefined. What's wrong with my loop?

Second Update:

```
    2015-02-01T20:38:20.900903+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2015-02-01T20:38:20.930258+00:00 app[web.1]: error: Script restart attempt #1
    2015-02-01T20:38:20.894952+00:00 app[web.1]: this is sender1 length  1
    2015-02-01T20:38:20.895077+00:00 app[web.1]: The for loop executed!
    2015-02-01T20:38:20.895465+00:00 app[web.1]: this is sender1 section ["54baf92d2b54840900dcb971"]
    2015-02-01T20:38:20.895504+00:00 app[web.1]: jj is 0
    2015-02-01T20:38:20.900455+00:00 app[web.1]: This is the from1 phone +19206398297
    2015-02-01T20:38:20.901052+00:00 app[web.1]: console.log('This is the section1 phone',sender1[jj].phone);
    2015-02-01T20:38:20.901050+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/packages/timeoff/server/controllers/timeoff.js:104
    2015-02-01T20:38:20.903068+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'phone' of undefined
    2015-02-01T20:38:20.901184+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                     ^
    2015-02-01T20:38:20.903071+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Promise.<anonymous> (/app/packages/timeoff/server/controllers/timeoff.js:104:53)
    2015-02-01T20:38:20.903072+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Promise.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:177:8)
    2015-02-01T20:38:20.903074+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Promise.emit (events.js:95:17)
    2015-02-01T20:38:20.903075+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Promise.emit (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:84:38)
    2015-02-01T20:38:20.903077+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Promise.fulfill (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:97:20)
    2015-02-01T20:38:20.903079+00:00 app[web.1]:     at model.Document.init (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:250:11)
    2015-02-01T20:38:20.903078+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1394:13
    2015-02-01T20:38:20.903081+00:00 app[web.1]:     at completeOne (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1392:10)
    2015-02-01T20:38:20.903082+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.cb (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1151:11)
    2015-02-01T20:38:20.903083+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object._onImmediate (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mquery/lib/utils.js:137:16)
    2015-02-01T20:38:20.922158+00:00 app[web.1]: error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8
    2015-02-01T20:38:21.737499+00:00 app[web.1]: Mean app started on port 55934 (development)
```

Here's the full code unformatted in hopes someone sees the nuances of what's breaking the loop:

```
User.find().where({
    code: req.body.Body.toUpperCase()
}).exec(function (err, sender1) {
    // Who sent the message?

    console.log('this is sender1 length ', sender1.length);

    for (var jj = 0; jj < sender1.length; jj = jj+1) {
        console.log('The for loop executed!');
    console.log('this is sender1 section', sender1[jj].section);
    console.log('jj is', jj);
        User.findOne({
            phone: req.body.From,
            section: sender1[jj].section
        }, function (err, from1) {
          console.log('This is the from1 phone',from1.phone);
          console.log('This is the section1 phone',sender1[jj].phone);
```

Comment: Have tried adding `console.log("i is: " + i)` to the loop?

Comment: Seems like an unlikely result! if the array has a value on the zero index, enters the loop etc, it's highly unlikely the index would be undefined, you're sure it's not just logging `undefined` for the `phone` property

Comment: Is it something to do with the value of i? Maybe I need to add or subtract 1 to i for some reason?

Comment: Not really -> http://jsfiddle.net/7bxv5uqk/

Comment: @Pointy when I replace i = i+1 with i++ and log i, this is what I get. i has been renamed to jj

Comment: OK well I don't see any `undefined` errors. Note that if you want to change that increment, it should be either `i=i+1` (perfectly fine) or `i++ ` but not `i=i++`. The answer originally posted about that part of your code was incorrect and you can ignore it.

Comment: There's the undefined error again when I change it back to jj = jj+1

Comment: It's common async pitfall. When callback is executed `jj` value has been changed.

Comment: Thanks Alexey! How would I fix it?

Comment: the [async package](https://github.com/caolan/async) is designed for this. Take a look at `.each()`, `.eachSeries()`, `.eachLimit()`